# Can I apply shorthand css to elements using jQuery's .css() method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to apply unknown styles to unknown selectors and it would seem that shorthand css cannot be applied using jQuery's `.css()` method. Is this correct? Is there a work-around?

Note that I am building the object dynamically to be passed in to the `.css()` and do not want to use `.css('background','#000')` syntax.

```
$('#example').css({background:'#000000 url("images/bg.gif") repeat-x scroll 0 0 transparent'});
```

The code above doesn't work. However, the code below does.

```
$('#example').css({background:'#000'});
```

And so does this.

```
$('#example').css({background:'url("images/bg.gif")'});
```

But when used together they naturally overwrite each other. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
background: #000000 url("images/bg.gif") repeat-x scroll 0 0 transparent;
```

… is invalid CSS. You've specified the background-color twice (#000000 and transparent). It should work if you use valid CSS.

That said, using classes and external stylesheets is usually a better bet.

Answer (score 2):

Your better option would be to have a set of pre-defined CSS classes in your CSS file and then apply those target styles on the fly as necessary.

This has the added benefit of keeping your jQuery code down to a readable and manageable level.

So instead of writing:

```
$('#example').css({background:'url("images/bg.gif")'});
```

You can opt for the simpler:

```
$('#example').addClass('myClass1');
```

Comment: I'm trying to apply unknown styles to unknown selectors so this isn't an option but would be the obvious choice.